# how to Size list view item according its child in flutter? dynamic list item size?

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

**Size list view item according its child contents**

in list view, you have to specify the list item height formally, but I want size
its height according to the child such as in the following image:

[image: ListView]

**Note: The data will be loaded from server.**

**The ListItemCode:**

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EditExperienceItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditExperienceItemWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text('1'),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        width: 1,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text('UI/UX Designer'),
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text('Gate Way'),
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text('27/12/2020 - 11/4/2021'),
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: 22,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            thickness: 1,
            indent: 30,
            endIndent: 30,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Text(
                'I felt really good at ZazaPay it was a very ui we did lots of stuff in a friendly place with very special people'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thoe Screen Code:

```
    import 'package:dozar/screen/edit_experience_screen/widget/edit_experience_item_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class EditExperienceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const EditExperienceScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10,),
                  Text(
                    'Edit Experiences',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return EditExperienceItemWidget();
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used the stateless custom widget, named EditExperienceItemWidget.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify height for the list view items. You can try this layout

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: responseList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index){ 
    return Container(
     //Add decoration to the container here
      child: Column( 
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       children: [
        //Design the card ui here
       ]
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: This error throws: 
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#37da8 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Have you added an expanded or flexible inside it?

Comment: Yeah, I added a flexible widget: 
I used the following structure: 
Column(
Flexible(Row()),
Divider(),
Flexible(Text()),
)

Comment: Remove flex from the column. Directly add row

Comment: Throws the same error: 
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#95d9b relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: Okay, i will add it now

Comment: The error is coming from the following code. Seems like you are abusing Flexible
`Flexible(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('UI/UX Designer'),
                      Text('Gate Way'),
                      Text('27/12/2020 - 11/4/2021'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),`

Comment: Remove the expanded widget above the list view

Comment: I removed the expanded widget, but it did not work.

Comment: To the column inside SafeArea add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min and add shrinkwrap true to the list view

Comment: In my opinion, the problem related to list item contianer size, because it will render the whole list according to the size, anytime when I specify the container's height, it works well, otherwise, the exception throws.

Comment: first try the code that  
Kaushik Chandru gave you with ordinary `Text` widgets as children of the `Column`, then try replacing them with your stuff

Comment: I didn't get you @pskink, could you please provide the full answer?
I provided everything you need, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: He's saying to use the minimal code that is in the answer with text widget. So you get the list working properly. Then add the ui one by one

Comment: exactly, this is what I meant

Comment: Define your container height like: 

height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Comment: No.. if you add height as MediaQuery.of(context).size.height then each element will be same height of the device. That's not how the UI looks.This container is each element in the list view